# Compatibility of impredicative Set and function extensionality

Tags: coq

The Coq [FAQ](https://coq.inria.fr/faq#htoc41) says that function extensionality is consistent with predicative `Set`. It's not fully clear to me from this whether it's consistent with impredicative `Set` (or maybe the consistency is unknown in that case).

Comment: This sounds a bit misleading; I imagine that it is consistent with impredicative Set as well. But that's probably a better question for the Coq mailing list.

Comment: Additionally, this question is about the theory of Coq rather than a programming issue with Coq and should probably be migrated to MathOverflow where it has more chances of being answered in details.

Comment: If you're considering migration then [cstheory.SE](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com) would be another good choice, imo.

Comment: This question has been mentioned by [Zimm i48](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3335288/zimm-i48) in [this](https://sympa.inria.fr/sympa/arc/coq-club/2016-12/msg00114.html) related Coq-Club thread ([this](https://sympa.inria.fr/sympa/arc/coq-club/2016-12/msg00115.html) post specifically).